# Are there any recent examples of political protests organized by diaspora?

Tags: protests

In August 2018, [Romanian diaspora organized a major political protest](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-romania-protests/anti-government-protest-in-romania-turns-violent-idUSKBN1KV1YO) in Bucharest:

> The protests were organized and promoted by groups of Romanians
>   working abroad, angry at what they say is entrenched corruption, low
>   wages and attempts by the PSD to weaken the judiciary in one of the
>   European Union’s most corrupt states.

I am wondering if some people living in another country organizing a protest in their native country is something rare or not. To narrow down, I am interested in post 1990 and EU countries only.

**Question:** Are there any recent examples of political protests organized by diaspora?

*Note:* by diaspora I mean its [general definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/diaspora) (people coming from a country living in other countries).

Comment: Not exactly protests, but there were reports that important number of Irish emigrees were returning to Ireland to vote in the referendum about the abortion law, this year.

Comment: Qualify "recent" and "organized by". There's the Iranian 1979 revolution etc. In fact being in the West was [more of an advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_Revolution#Khomeini_moves_to_the_West).

Comment: @Fizz The question says that the author is interested in "post 1990 and EU countries only", so the Iranian revolution would be out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lately (late 2020, early 2021), here are a fair bit of [anti-farm reform protests](https://globalnews.ca/news/7601730/why-many-british-columbians-continue-to-protest-indias-farm-laws/) being organized by the Indian diaspora, at least in Surrey, BC.

Protests concerning events out-of-country isn't very popular with everyone else given the pandemic.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find some of that with Serbia's history. With the whole Kosovo situation. If that counts toward your requirements. But that's more of a land dispute. That was during the 90's, but still ongoing to a lesser extent.

Comment: Could you add concrete examples and sources for examples in Serbia / Kosovo?

Comment: Any protests that were organized by people that had lived in a country and came back even for a couple of days to protest would be fine. As `jahn` said, at example will improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is the [BDS movement](https://bdsmovement.net/) within the Palestinian diaspora which works to end international support, and in particular, by the USA,  of Israels oppression of the Palestinians in the Occupied Territories, Gaza and the West Bank. Of course, this international support does not explicitly support the oppression, but in de facto does, especially since the failure of the Oslo process, which had been forseen by the Palestian academic & christian, Edward Said who had bluntly characterised it as a complete capitulation to Israeli demands. This is easily seen today, since at no time has Istael stopped encroaching upon land in the West Bank (apart from hiatus' now and again) and Gaza remains under seige behind a concrete wall and characterised as the Palestinians themselves as "the worlds largest open-air prison". Hence, it is easu to see that the USA, despite protestations to the contrary, and as expressly stated by Naseer Aruri's *Dishonest Broker: The Role of the US in Palestine and Israel*, is not an honest broker.

The BDS campaign works on three different levels: Academic, Cultural & Economic. Hence, Boycotts, Divestment and Sanction or BDS. The movement is directly inspired by the successful campaign within the West and South Africa to disband apartheid in South Africa in the seventies, eighties and early nineties. In fact, B'Tselem, a respected human rights organisation in Israel have recently come out to [state](https://www.btselem.org/topic/apartheid) explicitly that the oppression experienced by the Palestinians is aparthied as legally charactised by the 1973 Internation UN Convention on the Suppression and Punishment of Aparthied.

Comment: B'Tselem did not "recently" come out in favor of Palestinians. They exist since 1989 and were consistently fighting for Palestinian human rights from within Israel.

Comment: @Philipp: Isn't my prose clear enough for you to understand? I said that the "B'Tselem ... have recently come out to state explicitly that the oppression experienced by the Palestinians is *aparthied*" (italics added). The point you're making is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Phillip: Was this downvote due to your 'misunderstanding'? If so please rescind it. Or keep it, so long as you state personally that you do not like my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how BDS qualifies as a protest by the diaspora though. I think it's mostly non-Israelis who are involved in BDS.

Comment: @Fizz: If you look at the BDS page on wikipedia you'll see that it's said to be "Palestinian-led".

Comment: @MoziburUllah I didn't downvote your answer. I just pointed out something which is easy to misunderstand, in my opinion. The answer gives the impression that B'Tselem never cared about Palestinians and then suddenly saw the light thanks to the BDS movement. When in reality they supported Palestinian human rights long before BDS was a thing.

Comment: @Phillip: It's only a short text and not that easy to get wrong for someone used to scanning many texts. I'm already assuming that people interested in Israel-Palestime relations will know who B'Tselem are and what they are fighting for  which you most manifestly do. I was emphasing that this is the first time that an Israeli human rights organisation has described the situation as *aparthied*.  Apology not accepted.